# Output of shell_exec gets truncated to 100 characters

Tags: php, bash, shell, curl, shell-exec

When run in shell the following command,

```
curl -F file=@filename http://192.168.0.1
```

produces the following output:

```
Accuracy = 0% (0/1) (classification)
Accuracy = 0% (0/1) (classification)
Accuracy = 0% (0/1) (classification)
Accuracy = 0% (0/1) (classification)
verdict = success!
```

When I run it in php, either by using `shell_exec()`, `exec()` or the backtick operator,

```
$verdict = `curl -F file=@$filename $url`;
```

I get the following output:

```
Accuracy = 0% (0/1) (classification)
Accuracy = 0% (0/1) (classification)
Accuracy = 0% (0/1) (class
```

The output gets truncated at exactly 100 characters. I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is. Why is this, and how do I get the full output in a php variable?

Comment: Check if it's an apache server side permissions issue. That has been known to truncate the data, and since it's only happening with php, I would double check apache.

Comment: And why are you executing it by `exec()`? You can use `curl` directly in PHP.

Comment: please show the full php used

Comment: For instance (the backticks are showing up as code here) `$verdict = <backtick>curl -F file=@$filename $url<backtick>;`

Comment: How could I test for it to be a permission issue?

Comment: Did you check the server logs?  Those might provide a clue.  What does `ini_get('max_execution_time');` say?

Comment: `ini_get` returns `30`. I checked /var/log/apache2/error.log and there's nothing out of the ordinary. I'm not sure what other logs to check?

Comment: The question why the output gets truncated is by far more interesting than why he not using PHP curl.

Answer (score 0):

You may avoid executing the cURL operation via terminal because

- It is very likely that not every server will support executing the commands via code.
- It is very likely that the safe-mode is enabled in production.
- Not every user that executes the above command in terminal will have permission to execute.
- Not every user that executes the above command without specifying the full path of the command (like /usr/bin/curl)

Consider using PHP's built-in [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) option to implement this via

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS
```

Comment: I implemented the php option but I needed to apt-get it for my Ubuntu localhost. It works, in the sense that I'm getting a response back, but it's the same truncated version as above.

Comment: If one could not execute the command then why would its output be truncated? None of your points are addressing the OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced very similar issue. I was trying to count the number of instances of
a given process and the lines returned by `ps aux` were always truncated at position 80. I am not sure if my suggestion will resolve the discussed issue since you confirm getting 100 characters. I added `COLUMNS=9999` to the command to expand the output. In your case, that will look like:

```
COLUMNS=9999 curl -F file=@filename http://192.168.0.1
```